# This message was not sent to Spam because of a filter you created. OK but which filter?

Tags: gmail

Sometime I see:

[image]

How can I see which filter the yellow message is talking about? I don't want to search myself. "Edit Filters" redirects to https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#settings/filters.

Comment: I'm afraid your only recourse will go to your list of filters and edit each one and hit "Test Search" to see if this message gets caught.

Comment: I have about 160 filters, ale. Testing each one would take hours. It is disheartening that this problem has persisted for EIGHT YEARS, and STILL Google hasn't addressed it.

Answer (score 1):

Did  your filters apply a label to the message? Open up the filters page and use your browser's "search this page" feature (usually cmd or ctrl F) to find that label.

And/or look at the headers of your message and maybe you'll get an idea of what kinds of things your filters look for.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. This was exactly the issue I was having. Anything that didn't match domains I had personally whitelisted in a filter would receive a label so that I could keep corporate emails in my inbox and vendor emails separate. Therefore, spam was getting labeled and put into that label. Also, I had a label setup a long time ago that assigned "@" to anything addressed directly to me in order to sort it from emails sent to the team or organization. Since the spam was being sent directly to me, it would get labeled with "@" as well and not filtered out. Thanks for this!